# How to use Count in 2D Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, count

I have a 2D vector of strings and want to count how many times a certain word is repeated. For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< vector<string> > vec(4, vector<string>(4, "word") );
    count( vec.begin(), vec.end(), "certain word" );
}
```

But the above gives errors. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to iterate over the outer vector to get the inner vectors. Then you have to iterate over the inner vectors to count the "certain word" in the strings.

Comment: Does the inner vector already contain single words, or a string consisting of multiple words?

Comment: @user0042 Yes only single words.

Comment: @mhm Then you find the correct answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run count on search individual vector and sum the results:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< vector<string> > vec(4, vector<string>(4, "string of words") );
    size_t sum = 0;
    for(auto& v: vec) {
        sum += count( v.begin(), v.end(), "certain word" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to update the `count` call. And it doesn't count the words in the *strings*.

Comment: It worked.. had to change vec.begin() ... to v.begin()... thanks a lot sir.