# How to work and using function with vector<vector<>> in C++?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm a student and I'm using c++. In the time I learn online I can't find detail about how `vector<vector<>>` works.

I want to ask how to use function like `count()`, `find()` for this type of vector?

Such as I have a `vector<vector<int>> v= [[1,3],[2,3]]` how can I using count to count how many 3 in all the vector or to find the first vector that have 3.

I new so maybe my question hard to understand, thank you for reading.

When I try this:

```
find(v.begin() , v.end(),{v[0][1]} or find(v.begin() , v.end(),v[0][1])
```

it gives an error.

Comment: Please read this: [ask]. Then [edit] and add a [mcve].

Comment: It works like std::vector, just another level of indirection. Loop over the outer vector first and then you have an inner loop loping over the final elements.

Comment: Unrelated: `vector<vector<int>> v= [[1,3],[2,3]]` is not valid c++

Comment: *"In the time I learn online..."* I would recommend reading a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as in its current state, your question is not specific enough. We can't in general explain how `count` etc works on a 2D vector. For example, `vector<vector<int>> v= [[1,3],[2,3]]` **indicates that you're not using a good c++ book.** A book will help you a lot while online sites/articles will mostly teach bad programming habits.

Comment: [How to use Count in 2D Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127883/how-to-use-count-in-2d-vector)

Comment: Unless your vectors aren't all the same length a 1d vector with calculated indexes will generally be faster and avoids this problem. There's even a standard library class to help with this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan

Comment: *"to find the first vector that have 3"* -- In other words, to `find` the first vector in which you can `find` 3? *(Take a guess as to how often you might end up calling `find`.)*

Comment: Easy, don't. Use a proper (2D) array library for that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution without loops, like you seem to be needing.
Note the accumulate_threes_in_a_vector could also have been a lambda

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

// a function that adds the number of 3s in a vector to a sum
auto accumulate_threes_in_a_vector(std::size_t sum, const std::vector<int>& values)
{
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count
    // loop over the int vector and add the number of 3's
    return sum += std::count(values.begin(), values.end(), 3);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vector_of_vectors{
        {1, 2, 3}, 
        {3, 4, 3, 3},
        {3, 3}
    };

    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate
    // sum the number of 3s in the vector of vectors
    auto total = std::accumulate(vector_of_vectors.begin(), vector_of_vectors.end(), 0, accumulate_threes_in_a_vector);
    
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'm curious: why `sum +=`?

Comment: thank you very much. accumulate(vector_of_vectors.begin(), vector_of_vectors.end(), 0, accumulate_threes_in_a_vector); but what is the 0 in this function stand for ?

Comment: @longlong the 0 is the initial value. It's in the documentation of [`std::accumulate`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/)